# excel vba - Selenium Find Element

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

I'm using Selenium to do some webscraping.

I always struggle with finding elements when Name or ID isn't an options.

The page is
https://www.portfolio123.com/holdings.jsp?portid=1637063

And I'm trying to find the log in button.
the element looks like:
[image]

I've tried

```
FindElementByClass("btn-primary btn-sm", 10000)

FindElementsByLinkText("Log In", 10000)

FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='btn btn-primary btn-sm']//[@href='javascript:void(goToLoginPage())")
```

But without any success (I suspect I need to use XPath, but I can't seem to get it right

Any help please? (and if you could explain how to figure this out, so I don't have the issues in future that would be really appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element <kbd>Log In</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByLinkText*:

  ```
  FindElementByLinkText("Log In")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  FindElementByCss("a[href*='goToLoginPage']")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(@href, 'goToLoginPage')]")
  ```

Comment: thanks that worked too, I used linktext before, but i guess the ,1000 (which i thought was for timeout) messed it up

Answer (score 1):

I tested. try this code below code. its working for me..

Sub loginCode()

Dim bot As New WebDriver

bot.start "chrome", "https://www.portfolio123.com/holdings.jsp?portid=1637063"

bot.Get "/"

Call WaitForSec(5)

bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""wrapper""]/div/div/div/a[1]").Click

End Sub

Sub WaitForSec(Sec As Integer)

Dim lngTime As Long

```
lngTime = Timer
While Timer < lngTime + Sec
    DoEvents
Wend
```

End Sub

Comment: That xpath worked thanks.
for some reason .click didn't work for me though
but using sendkeys keys.enter did